# Ansible lineinfile skipping line

Tags: apache2, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, ansible

On my Ansible script, I'm using a loop to add lines to the apache2.conf file on the guest OS.  The lineinfile module inserts every line except the last one `</Directory>`.  Why is Ansible skipping the final line?  Thanks.

```
- name: test
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
    line: "{{ item.line }}"
  with_items: 
    - { line: <Directory /vagrant> }
    - { line: Options Indexes FollowSymLinks }
    - { line: AllowOverride All }
    - { line: Require all granted }
    - { line: </Directory> }
  notify:
    - restart apache2
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not reproducable. Are you sure there isn't a `</Directory>` tag higher in the file?

Here's the task I tested with:

```
  - name: test
    lineinfile:
      dest: foo.conf
      line: "{{ item.line }}"
    with_items: 
      - { line: <Directory /vagrant> }
      - { line: Options Indexes FollowSymLinks }
      - { line: AllowOverride All }
      - { line: Require all granted }
      - { line: </Directory> }
```

And the contents of `foo.conf`.

```
<Directory /vagrant>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

As an aside, use of `lineinfile` is often a sign that the file (apache2.conf in this case) is not in configuration management. Many scary things can happen that will throw this off. You'd be much better off putting apache2.conf in your configuration management. (e.g., deploy it with Ansible). Alternately, you can at least use a `conf.d` file so Ansible can "own" the entire file.

Comment: Strong emphasis on "You'd be much better off putting apache2.conf in your configuration management" and I would recommend using the template module for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in module `lineinfile`.

Line `</Directory>` has presents in file apache2.conf, and Ansible `lineinfile` skipping it.

I have reported [this bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/2054) to Ansible team.

Answer (score 0):

Note as of Ansible 2.0 (released Jan 2016, after this question was asked) this would be best implemented with `blockinfile`:

```
- name: insert vagrant directory
  blockinfile:
    path: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
    block: |
      <Directory /vagrant>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
      </Directory>
  Match User ansible-agent
  PasswordAuthentication no
```

ref: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/blockinfile_module.html